# Multi-Master K8S cluster fails when half of the masters are down

Tags: kubernetes, cluster, disaster-recovery

i have a 4 masters HA K8S cluster , (accross 2 datacenters , 2 in each site) , but the kubectl command stops working after shuting down 2 masters , is this the expected behaviour?

I want the cluster to survive a Datacenter crash.

PS : I am using 2 HA proxy + Keepalived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your master would host etcd containers, are they? Then this is expected, yes.

Check [etcd FAQ](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance). A 4 nodes cluster would indeed have a failure tolerance of 1 member. You would need 5 members, to allow for 2 failures. Though the recommended sizing running Kubernetes is usually 3.

Multi-datacenter deployments can be complicated: latency in between etcd members would be an issue. If this is fine with you, to survive a DC crashing, then you need 3 DC. Otherwise, you'ld better look into setting up individual clusters, and implementing failovers/replication on top of those.